# SoapClient::SoapClient in codeigniter

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, wsdl, soap-client

I am using this code

```
$userName=$this->input->post('user');
$password=$this->input->post('pass');
$lineNumber=$this->input->post('line');
$to= $this->input->post('Receiver');
$text=$this->input->post('messageBody');;

$client= new SoapClient('http://n.sms.ir/ws/SendReceive.asmx?wsdl');

$parameters['userName'] = $userName;
$parameters['password'] = $password;
$parameters['mobileNos'] = array(doubleval($to));
$parameters['messages'] = array($text);
$parameters['lineNumber'] = $lineNumber;
$parameters['sendDateTime'] = date("Y-m-d")."T".date("H:i:s");
print_r($client->SendMessageWithLineNumber($parameters));
```

But this happens

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:
>   SoapClient::SoapClient(http://n.sms.ir/ws/SendReceive.asmx?wsdl):
>   failed to open stream: Connection timed out
>
> Filename: views/sms.php
>
> Line Number: 19

and

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load
>   external entity "http://n.sms.ir/ws/SendReceive.asmx?wsdl"
>
> Filename: views/sms.php
>
> Line Number: 19

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: I cleaned your syntax up some so the errors were easier to read. Based on the errors, your server cannot open the WSDL address. Can you verify that it can open it? If it's a linux server, try `wget`

Answer (score 0):

go to file `system/core/CodeIgniter.php` and increase `set_time_limit` by default it set 300

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
    {
        @set_time_limit(300);//increase it according to your requirement
    }
```